# How can a user report another user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a User model. A user can be an employer or a student. So there is an employer model and a student model. They both belong to user. Only employers can view student profiles. So if there is something wrong with the profile, the employer should be able to report the profile. I was thinking of having a "report" button on the profile which only the employers can see. Then when they click on it, the admin (me) gets an email with the url or the id of the student.

Right now, the student profile url looks like `www.mywebsite.com/students/john-big`. How can the report button be setup so the whole URL or the user-id (John-big) gets emailed to me.

The mailer is set up already because I set it up in a way where I get an email every time a user signs up. I can use the same logic to email myself, but grabbing the ID or url is the problem. What is the best way to do it?

**Userinfo controller (userinfo =student):**

```
class UserinfosController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_userinfo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :log_impression]
    before_action :authenticate_user!


    def index
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @userinformation = current_user.build_userinfo
    end

    def create
        @userinformation = current_user.build_userinfo(userinfo_params)
        if @userinformation.save
          redirect_to userinfo_path(@userinformation)
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @userinformation.update(userinfo_params)
            redirect_to userinfo_path(@userinformation)
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @userinformation.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end


    private
        def userinfo_params
            params.require(:userinfo).permit(:name, :email, :college, :gpa, :major)
        end

        def find_userinfo
            @userinformation = Userinfo.friendly.find(params[:id])
        end
end
```

**Employer controller:**

```
class EmployersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_employer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index 
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @employer = current_user.build_employer
    end

    def create
        @employer = current_user.build_employer(employer_params)
        if @employer.save
          redirect_to userinfos_path
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @employer.update(employer_params)
            redirect_to employer_path(@employer)
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @employer.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    private
        def employer_params          
            params.require(:employer).permit(:paid, :name, :company, :position, :number, :email, :emp_img)
        end

        def find_employer
            @employer = Employer.friendly.find(params[:id])
        end 
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :userinfo
  has_one :employer

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  acts_as_messageable

  after_create :welcome_send

  def welcome_send
    WelcomeMailer.welcome_send(self).deliver_now
  end

end
```

Please let me know if you guys need more information.

Comment: You can use `user_info_url(@user_info)` or you can simply shows the id inside the mailer view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `request.url()` to get the URL of your view (the student profile url).

Try adding this to you view to get a feeling of it:

```
<%= debug("request.url: #{request.url()}") if Rails.env.development? %>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it works. What do you think is the best way to send that to myself? Can I create a button called "report", and when someone clicks on it, it mails the url to me? Is this possible?

Comment: You're welcome. Sending emails in Rails is a whole subject in itself. You have to configure a mailer. Anyway, my quick take is: Create a form in the relevant view for that report button, say form_button. When clicking the button, the form_button form should route to a report action in the relevant controller. From that controller action, generate the email.

Comment: Oh ok. I already have a mailer set up. Right now, when a user signs up, I get an email to my admin-email. I update the question to include that code. Is it going to be similar?

Comment: For sending the email from the controller, I guess you can basically copy-paste the existing code. To complete my precedent comment, I would use a *hidden field* in the form form_button, that would be pre-populated with the value of the relevant student profile url...